# How to configure common properties for all persistence units in OSGi (e.g. envers config)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, osgi, entitymanager, hibernate-envers

I am running an application on an OSGi framework (using karaf) with several bundles defining their own persistence units. The persistence units are defined declarative in persistence.xml files in each bundle.

My question is: Is there a way to provide a common configuration to all persistence units in all bundles?

To be more concrete: I am using hibernate and am trying to introduce hibernate-envers for revisioning. For obvious reasons all entity manger factories (which corresponds to the SessionFactory in hibernate) should use the same envers configuration, such as the prefix for the revision tables.

I did not find a way to define configuration properties in a central place, which are used by all registered entity manager factories.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to do this (assuming you use Aries JPA).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, your assumption is correct.